# Workflow Rule Criteria Not Properly Evaluated By Salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I have created a Workflow in Salesforce to send an email if a certain question that has a range of choices (1 to 4) has a response below 3. To be sure that my Workflow will only get triggered for a specific question I have to include in the Rule Criteria a hard-coded Question ID from the Survey Question object. The problem is, Salesforce cannot evaluate the condition to true even if the value is equal to the criteria as can be seen by the attached debug log below:

[image: Workflow Debug Log]

**Question**: Why would Salesforce not evaluate my condition as true? Anybody has an idea or has encountered this same situation?

Comment: What's your actual condition's code? You might be victim of the 15 vs 18-char long IDs. I know debug log displays both as 15. Try to write the condition passing both values to `CASESAFEID()` and comparing that?

Comment: The actual condition code is as can be seen in my WF debug log (using hard-coded Id). You can see in my debug log that I used the 15 char Id but I also tried using the 18 char Id with the same result. You can also see that the actual value of the field being tested is displayed in the log and is very much equal to the hard-coded Id in my condition (both underlined with blue). I will try your CASESAFEID() suggestion and will give you feedback. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @mpSchrader for the edit. My first question here in stack overflow. Inline attachment is what I was actually looking for :) I hope that somebody else encountered this issue. This is making me think that Salesforce has a bug in their workflow rule criteria evaluation.

Comment: No worries about the formatting. We are all here to help. :-)